# angularjs $scope and $http

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I'm facing a strange problem, here is code:

```
$scope.registeredCompanies = []; 
$scope.viewCompanies = function(){
    $http.get("server/loadCompanies.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.registeredCompanies = data;
        //console.log($scope.registeredCompanies);
        //1st log
    });
    console.log($scope.registeredCompanies);
    //2nd log
    $state.transitionTo('viewreRegisteredCompanies');
}
```

And here is loadCompanies.php:

```
require "connection.php";
$query = "select * from company where 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$companies = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    array_push($companies, $row);
echo json_encode($companies);
```

Now, if I log `$scope.registeredCompanies` at 1st log i.e within `$http.get().success()`, it logs successfully i.e data is pulled successfully but if I log out of the promise/.success() i.e at 2nd log place, object again goes to no value i.e array gets empty or if I initialize array with some values, it logs those initial values to console, **REMEMBER** companies are more than one means there is no chance that PHP file returns zero record.

Comment: very simple...ajax is asynchronous. You can't access the data in second log because it hasn't been returned yet. Also unless you store that data in a service when you transition away the scope is destroyed. Not clear why you would want to update scope, then move to another state

Comment: Completely correct and normal